# Craft Commerce: Create new shipping zone by excluding other zones

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, shipping

I need to create 3 shipping zones in Craft Commerce 2 (currently on v2.1.7):

- UK
- Europe
- Rest Of The World

Having to manually add the countries to the **UK** and **Europe** zones isn't too much of an issue, but do I have to manually add all the remaining countries to the **Rest Of The World** zone? Or is there a way to create a zone just by excluding countries from the other zones I've created (e.g. **Rest Of The World** should be all countries except the countries in the **UK** and **Europe** zones)?

Comment: I've created a EU zone manually. But I would be highly interested in a exclusion function as well.